# Clear swagger Cache for Jersey project

Tags: caching, jersey, glassfish-3, swagger

I have created Java `RESTFUL` web serivces using `Jersey`, I am using `swagger` for API documentation. however  swagger annotation changes during development for my RESTFUL services are not visible, I have tried clearing browser cache and used other browsers as well, but new changes does not reflect on Swagger API documentation. Swagger core dependencies are located in shared libraries directory.

**Wokaround**
In order for the changes to take effect I have to delete the following folders in Glass-fish.

1. generated
2. osgi-cache

and then redeploy the application (this require complete shutdown of the Glass fish server, otherwise system does not allow me to delete above folders.)

**My Questions:**
1 - Is there any way we can permanently disabled the caching?

2 - Is there any method to clear swagger cache on demand without restarting or deleting the folders?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you use hot swapping during development or do you deploy the whole application each time?

Comment: deploy whole application each time.

Comment: This is a bit odd. If you redeploy the whole application and restart the server, there shouldn't be any caching issues at all.

Comment: This is swagger internal caching problem. I am using "swaggerVersion": "1.2". i changed my apiVersion but it is still showing me older api version for "apis" endpoints (api/api-docs/pet) also it is not picking annotations for @ApiResponses e.t.c

Comment: That's the version of the Swagger specification, not the version of swagger-core. Which version is that, by the way? And the caching is a runtime thing, so once you shut the app down, the caching should be gone.

Comment: swagger-jaxrs_2.10 version: 1.3.10

Comment: Is the swagger-core dependency part of your WAR file or is it located in Glassfish's shared libraries directory?

Comment: It is located in shared libraries directory

Comment: That could be the reason then. Assuming you have some kind of a bootstrap code for your application, you can try to add com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing.ApiListingCache.invalidateCache() to that part of your code.

Comment: it is working for 
com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingCache.invalidateCache()

Could you please add it as answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments above, the solution is to use `com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingCache.invalidateCache()` during the start up of the application.

It should be noted that for some version of swagger-core, some parts are static and as such, using it as a shared lib will override the definitions for *all* the applications that use it on the same application server. The better solution would be to include the swagger-core dependency in each application separately.